# What are the difference and relation between the concepts of business process and business strategy?

Tags: microeconomics

What are the difference and relation between the concepts of [business process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process) and [business strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_management)?

For example, the process of strategy planning consists of the following steps:

- formulate missions and goals
- conduct external analysis to identify opportunities and threats in external competitive environment
- conduct internal analysis to identify strengths and weaknesses in internal operating environment
- formulate strategies, according to the missions and goals, opportunities and threats and strengths and weaknesses.
- implement formulated strategies
- monitor and control the execution of implemented strategies

Is business process involved in some step(s) of the strategic planning process?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business, not economics.

Comment: I agree with denesp.

Comment: There seems to be no suitable site within Stack Exchange for questions about business.  However if you google "business process" and "business strategy" there are many sites that explain these terms.